# How do I interpret "add +1/3 to natural armor bonus"?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation

I am new to Pathfinder and am building a Half-Orc Druid.

> **Half-Orcs**
>  
>   ***Favored Class Options***
>  
>   *The following options are available to all half-orcs who have the listed favored class, and unless otherwise stated, the bonus applies
>   each time you select the class reward.*
>  Druid: Add +1/3 to the
>   druid's natural armor bonus when using wild shape.

I do not understand how to interpret the "+1/3" text. There are two values separated by a slash. I assume the slash represents a condition. If so, what is this condition?

Furthermore, if I chose this bonus each time I selected the class reward, how would it accumulate on my AC?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This doesn't make any sense unless you look at what a Favored Class Ability is (emphasis mine):

> Instead of receiving an additional skill rank or hit point **whenever they gain a level in a Favored Class**, some races have the option of choosing from a number of other bonuses, depending upon their Favored Classes.

So what this means is that, because you're a Half-Orc, each time you level up you have the option to choose a +⅓ bonus (read as "plus one-third of a point bonus") to natural AC while in wildshape, instead of skill points. You don't get the +⅓ at first level, once, for being a Half-Orc – as a Half-Orc you get the *option* every level.

But what good is choosing a fraction of a +1? Normally fractions of bonuses are rounded down, but if you choose this option three times, during three level-ups, it will add up to a full +1 since ⅓ + ⅓ + ⅓ = 1. Over the course of multiple levels, that can mean a significant boost to your wildshape AC.

Comment: Actually, the choice of AC instead of skill points or HP is made once and for all, at chargen.

Comment: @Trajan That's not implied or said [in the text I'm reading](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/character-advancement). Where do you get that? The normal rule is that you can choose between *either* skill points or hit points each level. My understanding is that the APG merely adds another option, not forces a chargen choice between normal and APG favoured class benefits. That's the most obvious reading of the text I quoted above, even.

Comment: Here's the SRD source : http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/character-advancement (in **Favored class** section) It's not quite as clear on this point as my french rulebook, though.

Comment: @Trajan I think there must be a mistranslation in the French book, since that page you linked implies often it's optional each level, and then at the end says it explicitly: "This is not a permanent or irrevocable choice; just as characters could alternate between taking skill ranks and hit points when they gain levels in their favored class, these benefits provide a third option, and characters may freely alternate between them."

Comment: @SevendSidedDie I looked on french wikis and the misunderstanding seems pretty common, and there's no official errata about this. Shame.

Comment: Translations are evil. In the Italian one the paladin uses the surges of his targets when he lays on hands.

Answer (score 8):

It is a fractional bonus, as described in [the rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/character-advancement).  These types of bonuses were introduced in the advanced player's guide.

> ... some of these alternate favored class benefits only add +1/2, +1/3, +1/4, or +1/6 to a roll (rather than +1) each time the benefit is selected; when applying this result to the die roll, round down (minimum 0). For example, a dwarf with Rogue as his favored class adds +1/2 to his trap sense ability regarding stone traps each time he selects the alternate Rogue favored class benefit; though this means the net effect is +0 after selecting it once (because +1/2 rounds down to +0), after 20 levels this benefit gives the dwarf a +10 bonus to his trap sense (in addition to the base value from being a 20th-level Rogue).

Ignore how it specifies rolls; the intent of the half-orc feature is clear.  You'd apply the bonus to your natural armor class, rounding down.  It'd give +1 AC for every 3 times you took it.

Since a hit point or skill point is probably less than a third of a feat (no one liked 3.5 Toughness!), a great many of these optional types of bonuses are actually a bit overpowered.  (Or a lot overpowered, in the case of the ones that grant extra spells known.  What the heck were they thinking?)